# Convert traditional message produces/queue to a flux in reactor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactor

I have the existing interface chain with many `MessageProducer` implementations.

```
interface MessageProducer {
    void produce(MessageQueue messageQueue);
}

interface MessageQueue {
    void submit(Message message);
}
```

How to adapt that to a [reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) `Flux` with as few interface changes as possible? Something like

```
class FluxMessageQueueAdapter implements MessageQueue {
   private Flux<Message> flux = ... 

   public void submit(Message message) {
      flux.next(message);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that one solution could be

```
MessageProducer producer = 
Flux.push((emitter) -> {
            FluxMessageQueueAdapter adapter = new FluxMessagerQueueAdapter(emitter);
            producer.produce(adapter);
            emitter.complete();
    })
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Did it work? Do you have a working example based on your idea?

Comment: I love the reactor-idea but in the end decided to leave it because I was unable to curb the caveats it came with. So no, I guess I didn't find a satisfying solution.